# Isn't the note below a contradiction in relation to paragraphs (2.1) and (2.2) in [basic.start.main]/2?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[basic.start.main]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2):

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function
>   shall not be overloaded. Its type shall have C++ language linkage and
>   it shall have a declared return type of type int, but otherwise its
>   type is implementation-defined. An implementation shall allow both
>
> (2.1) a function of `()` returning `int` and
>   (2.2) a function of `(int,` pointer to pointer to `char)` returning `int`
>
> as the type of `main`
>   ([dcl.fct]). In the latter form, for purposes of exposition, the first
>   function parameter is called `argc` and the second function parameter is
>   called `argv`, where `argc` shall be the number of arguments passed to the
>   program from the environment in which the program is run. If `argc` is
>   nonzero these arguments shall be supplied in `argv[0]` through
>   `argv[argc-1]` as pointers to the initial characters of null-terminated
>   multibyte strings (NTMBSS) ([multibyte.strings]) and `argv[0]` shall be
>   the pointer to the initial character of a NTMBS that represents the
>   name used to invoke the program or `""`. The value of `argc` shall be
>   non-negative. The value of `argv[argc]` shall be `0`. [ **Note: It is
>   recommended that any further (optional) parameters be added after
>   argv. — end note** ]

Comment: It says an implementation shall allow both, but not only both.

Comment: Why do you feel this is a contradiction?

Comment: Please specify what exactly you consider the contradiction. It is not clear to me how you interpret the mentioned parts of the quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It states that at least two signatures must be permitted; `int main()` and `int main(int, char**)`.

What other types are permitted is implementation-defined.

They recommend that if your implementation permits `main` with *more* arguments, that they be added *after* the `int, char**` arguments of that particular signature.  This is not forced.

The implementation could say that this is a valid `main` signature:

```
int main( std::vector<std::string> args )
```

or it could have:

```
int main( int, char**, system::permission_token )
```

or whatever.

This second one -- the `system::permission_token` -- where that is an optional argument (ie, `int main(int, char**)` still works), would be what the note advises.  The first style is still permitted.

Comment: The quote "but otherwise its type is implementation-defined" could very well refer to the return type of the function, and not to other arguments. At least that was my interpretation.

Comment: @WaldB Sure, you misread it.  The but clause does not remove the "shall" requirement from the first part of the phrase.  The type of a function includes its return value, its arguments, and (in later versions of C++) if it is noexcept.  All `main` functions **must** return `int` (part 1 of sentence), but everything else is implementation defined about its type (part 2 of the sentence).  It then goes on to further restrict what the implemenation can define (saying it must support two different signatures, without limiting it to supporting those two).

Comment: I would say that your previous comment makes sense to me. But I don't agree that anyone (including native English speakers) could arrive at this conclusion, just by reading the standard.

Comment: @WaldB Probably the fact that "shall" has a very specific meaning in ISO standards might have tripped you up.

Comment: Could you comment on this specific meaning?

Comment: @WaldB https://www.iso.org/foreword-supplementary-information.html ; and, if it applied to the return type, then that "shall" would not be a requirement, because *anything* could fullfill it.